# How do I know which platform a given .NET assembly targets?

Tags: c#, .net, com, interop, com-interop

In my C# project I add a reference to a COM object and an interop assembly is generated.

How do I know which platform (x86, x64, AnyCpu) this interop assembly targets?

Comment: I don't understand the reason you even need to know this information.  Can you explain what you are trying to do exactly?  You can easily figure out if you are on a x86 or x64 operating system.  In the case of AnyCPU it would work on either platform.  You should as a developer know the COM object ( if it was written in .NET ) was targeted to a specfic platform or not.

Comment: @Ramhound: That's important - the COM object is out-proc, so only the interop is loaded into the consumer process. If the consumer process is 64-bit and the interop is targeted to x86 it won't load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use CorFlags.exe, see the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164699%28VS.80%29.aspx) link. (Run from the VS command line, just point it to your assembly)
**EDIT:** Here's another [link](http://www.geekpedia.com/Thread27309_How-Do-I-Tell-If-A-DLL-Is-X86-X64-Or-AnyCpu.html) with more info than MSDN